# Passing LatLng object into javascript?

Tags: php, json, google-maps

I am using php to write out an html file, similar to a user profile, that contains a google map centered at the profile's address.

I know that the latitude/longitude is returned in latlng object format. Can I just parse this object out of the json using php, and pass it directly into the javascript, or is it not possible for php to pass this object? Furthermore, can this information be stored in an sql database (without using fusion table)?

**edit:** so if I had

```
    $geoadd = $address.','.$city.','.$state.','.$zipcode.',USA';
    $geoadd = urlencode($geoadd);
    $url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/output?address=".$geoadd;
    $json_response = json_decode($url, TRUE);
```

I'd just pass $json_response into javascript?

Comment: I don't know why you would want to decode JSON in PHP just to send it to JavaScript, but yes it is possible.  If I were you, I would wait to parse it until it reaches your JS, and just have PHP pass it along untouched.

Comment: [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make use of an ajax call and parse the gocoder responce in there.Just make use of [jquery ajax call](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).